# Style Sheet is not linking with html?

Tags: html, css

I have following scenario.

I have Created a Web folder on my desktop which contains the html file Test.html and another folder styles which contains the myStyle.css file.

I am trying to link .css file with my html using the following code but it is not working.

How can i do this ?

Here is my Code :

```
<head>
   <link href="Web/styles/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Comment: First of all fix the title with <title>My first WebPage</title> then can you please send the right structure of your folders? :)

Comment: And how do you know it's not loading. Have you checked using the developer tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test.html` is *inside* the `Web` folder, so you don't have to enter the `Web` folder when you look relative to the HTML document.

You are trying to read `$HOME\Desktop\Web\Web\styles\myStyle.css`.

Remove the `Web/` portion of the URI.

```
href="styles/myStyle.css"
```

---

You should also have a space between attributes.

```
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
```

Comment: I enclose my title in the title attribute and put spaces in attributes and types and it worked thanks

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your folder structure is something like this:

```
Web
  |--styles
  |      |--myStyle.css
  |--Test.html
```

If you reference the stylesheet from `Test.html`, you should specify the path *relative* to the location of `Test.html`. Specifying `Web` is not a good idea, because the directory that contains `Test.html` - which is `Web` - does not have a subdirectory called `Web`.

If the structure is the way I have shown above, the path should be `styles/myStyle.css`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to enclose My first WebPage in a title tag:

```
<title>My first WebPage</title>
```

Then what you need to do is specify the href attribute as a relative path, so assuming that your css is in a directory called styles the link would be:

```
<link href="styles/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Also, make sure there is a space between " and type in your link tag.

I hope this helps